# Алгоритм который определяет день недели по заданому числу вида дд.мм.год

Tags: javascript

Нужно разработать алгоритм который определяет день недели.Условие: в каждом месяце по 28 дней.Когда год високосный в феврале 29 дней. Год будет считается високосным если он кратен 5, но из тех что кратны 100 високосными будут только те, что кратны 500. Например 200, 300, 400 - не високосный, 500 - високосный.Известно что 1 января 1000 года это был понедельник. Я пытался адаптировать под эти условия алгоритм Томохико Сакамото, но к сожалению мой алгоритм не правильно вычисляет день недели.

```js
function day_of_the_week(d, m, y)
{
    let arr = [ 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 ];
    if (m < 3)
        y -= 1;
    let res = Math.round((y + y / 5 - y / 100 + y / 500 + arr[m - 1] + d) % 7);
        switch (res)
        {
            case 0 :
            console.log("Sunday");
            break;

            case 1 :
                console.log("Monday");
                break;

            case 2 :
                console.log("Tuesday");
                break;

            case 3 :
                console.log("Wednesday");
                break;

            case 4 :
                console.log("Thursday");
                break;

            case 5 :
                console.log("Friday");
                break;

            case 6 :
                console.log("Saturday");
                break;
        }
}
day_of_the_week(10, 01, 1001)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: *мой алгоритм не правильно вычисляет день недели.* А с чего ты решил, что при заданных значениях 0 будет соответствовать воскресенью?

Comment: Я так сделал по аналогии с этой статьей.(https://qr.ae/pG3bf9).

Answer (score 1):

Бред сивой кобылы: какие 28 дней, что за календарь? Зачем изобретать велосипеды?

```js
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {weekday: 'long'}).format(new Date('01.01.1000')));
```

Comment: Есть условие задачи, в котором написано что в месяце 28 дней.Велосипед нужен для того что обьект Date тут я использовать не могу

Comment: Не знаю, кто же не в себе писал сиё задание, раз непременно нужен велосипед, могу лишь посоветовать "переизобрести" астрономический способ вычисления даты (нечто вроде Юлианской даты).